# How to sync android studio Bookmarks on other computer?

Tags: android-studio

How to sync android studio **Bookmarks** on other computer?

is there any cloud service or local files to copy ,to sync **bookmarks** between different computers?

Answer (score 0):

solved by intellj official team . they told me to copy local config files by  manually for now .
The bookmarks are stored in the workspace files for each project; you can find them in the workspace folder inside the configuration directory. To find out which file contains the workspace for the particular project, use Project ID that can be found in the project **.idea/workspace.xml** folder, for example:

```
<component name="ProjectId" id="2IUvDeaykLf5XLO3EHfpWLBq82w" />
```

so you can consider copying it manually to your other device